# LIKE doesn't return results

Tags: laravel

I am trying to find "sam" inside FullName in the table users with this eloquent operation:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', $input)->orWhere('fullName', 'LIKE', "%$input%")->find(10);
```

finding through id works as expected but the Where with LIKE isn't returning any results.

(if $input is 1 the first where returns a result but if $input is sam the second where doesn't return anything)

In the database fullName has the value "Sam Pettersson".

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know laravel but does this make any difference ? `$user = User::where('id', '=', $input)->orWhere('fullName', 'LIKE', '%'.$input.'%')->find(10);`

Comment: @Ours Nope, just writing '%sam%' didn't work either.

Comment: `find` used to FIND row by ID, so if ID with value equal to `10` is not found in results returned from LIKE selection - the selection HAS NO RESULTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason laravel doesn't want find() and like queries in the same query so using this instead worked:

```
$user = User::where('id', '=', $input)->orWhere('fullName', 'LIKE', "%$input%")->take(10)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = User::where(function($query) use($input)
{
  $query->where('id', '=', $input)
        ->orWhere('fullName','LIKE', '%'.$input.'%');
})->get();
```

This worked for me. Hope this work for you.